# Setting up a sonic wall to allow remote acces to two servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, sonicwall

I am adding an exchange server to our network and I want to be able to remote into the server from home.

Right now we have a file server which we can already remote into. We use the public ip address of x.x.x.x to remote in. When I try to use the wizard to create a new object it keeps giving me the same x.x.x.x to log into the second server I think.

How can you add multiple servers to the firewall to remote into?

Are sonicwall is a TZ105

thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you not using VPN, but just allowing your severs to be accessible via the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

If you **REALLY** need to do that without VPN, you will need to create a NAT policy (Network > NAT Policies) to translate the incoming requests from WAN to your LANor DMZ and also an firewall policy to allow those requests (Firewall > Access Rules).